# Which Darwin book (and today edition) is illustrated by his own drawings?

Tags: evolution, zoology, literature

I am interested in buying Charles Darwin books and mostly drawings (nowadays editions, I am not a collector). Please, can you advise in which book and which edition I can find the most of his drawings? I found some books as On the Origin of Species ad the Geology of The Voyage of The Beagle but I am not sure if there are his drawings too. I am a student so I couldn't spend too much money on it, but I was interested in his texts and drawings, supporting each other in one book/journal/publication. Thank you !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe that there is only one drawing in the first edition of *On the Origin of Species*, and it is Darwin's.  Any good edition such as the [fascimile edition with an introduction by Ernst Mayr](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0674637526), will include this drawing.  I'm not sure about other editions of the *Origin* or other books of Darwin's.  However, maybe you don't need to buy anything.  [Darwin Online](http://darwin-online.org.uk/) is a wonderful collection that includes many (all?) of Darwin's writings over the years, including *images* of many of them; the drawings are no doubt included.

It's possible that the [History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/) StackExchange site would be a better place for this question.

Comment: Very good answer +1. I did not know about History_of_Science_and_Math.SE. Darwin Online is a nice resource as well.

Comment: Thank you @Mars, I neither didn't know about History of Science... thanks for the book link and  Darwin online, I also found this resource later. Thank you again ! :)